# Html send userinput to td

Tags: html, ajax

When I gave an input(text) in the textfield and the text that i input is appearing in TD and then its always gone.

first_name is the userinput

f1 is the td

```
function ajax_post(){
    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;                                
    var table = $("#f1");
   table.text(fn);
 }
```

my submit button

```
  <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onClick="ajax_post();">
```

i'm using `<form> </form>`

i'm wondering that my script is kinda wrong

Comment: Submitting the form reloads the current page. You need to either prevent the default submit - or not use a submit button in the first place. And maybe not even a form, because if you don't want to use the form to send the data, it is superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ajax_post(){
  var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
  var table = document.getElementById("f1");
  table.innerText = fn;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form onsubmit="return false;">
      <input type="text" id="first_name" />
      <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onClick="ajax_post();">
    </form>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="f1"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```